# How to make gcc uses march=native as default?

Tags: gcc, gcc4

Is there a way to change the specs file so that it will pass `-march=native` if nothing is specified in command line?

Related things in the default specs file is:

```
*cc1:
%(cc1_cpu)

*cc1_cpu:
%{march=native:%>march=native %:local_cpu_detect(arch)   %{!mtune=*:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}} %{mtune=native:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}
```

I am not sure how specs works.  Simply specifying `-march=native` before or after `%(cc1_cpu)` doesn't work.  However, this line does take effect because GCC will report error if I put `-something_wierd` instead of `-march=native`.

Another thing I noticed is if I put `%{march=i386:-something_wierd}` before `%(cc1_cpu)`, gcc reports error so looks like `-march=i386` is always passed in if nothing is specified, so is there a way to distinguish between nothing specified and `-march=i386` in specs file?

BTW, what does `%>` do?  Seems like it is not specified [in the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Spec-Files.html).

I am using MinGW's `gcc-4.6.2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Referring to your last question:** The gcc 4.6.1 sources (`gcc/gcc.c`) contain the following comment on `%>`:

```
 %>S    Similar to "%<S", but keep it in the GCC command line.
```

For the sake of completeness following the comment for `%<` form the same file:

```
 %<S    remove all occurrences of -S from the command line.
        Note - this command is position dependent.  % commands in the
        spec string before this one will see -S, % commands in the
        spec string after this one will not.
```

---

**To answer the first question in short:** yes, but ....

... the only generic solution I found has the significant drawback that the `-march` option will be ignored, so every build is done as if `-march=native` had been specified. Anyhow there is a workaround to that.

*1 The solution (without workaround)*

Create a specs-file called let's say `specs.nativealways` containing:

```
*cc1_cpu:
%<march=* -march=native %>march=native %:local_cpu_detect(arch) %{!mtune=*:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)} %{mtune=native:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}
```

When using the specs-file (for example by invoking `gcc` with the option `-specs=specs.nativealways`) the build will be done as if `-march=native` was specified (with the mentioned drawback that any occurrence of option `-march=<arch>` would have simply been ignored).

*2 The workaround*

To still by able to override the newly configured default behavior one can use a modified version of the specs-file described above, introducing a new option called `-myarch` using the same syntax as `-march` (except for `-myarch=native`, which won't work, which does not metter as `native` now is the default).

The modfied specs-file looks like this:

```
*cc1_cpu:
%<march=* %{myarch=*:%<myarch* -march=%* ; :-march=native %>march=native %:local_cpu_detect(arch) %{!mtune=*:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}}  %{mtune=native:%>mtune=native %:local_cpu_detect(tune)}
```

---

PS: This has been tested with with gcc 4.6.2 on Linux, but should work on MinGW.

Comment: I actually came out with some similar solution to your first approach.  I actually realized that the major problem is -march=i386 is always passed in by default and there is no way to tell if it passed in by default or through command line.  I guess changing the GCC source code is almost the only way.

Answer (score 2):

While not a direct answer to your question, you can reach a very similar effect by defining `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` in your shell's initialization file. 99% of the Makefiles are sufficiently standard to pick up the environment values and pass the flags to `gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
*cc1_cpu:
+ %{!march*:-march=native}
```

Comment: this won't work, if I remember correctly (the question was too old).  The reason is cc1 doesn't accept native as parameter to -march.  It actually calls local_cpu_detect to have a correct value to -march.

Comment: @icando The important part is `%{!march*:`. This will only match if `-march=` is not in the command line, meaning you get a "default" if nothing else is specified. I don't know anything about the actual -march parameters.

Comment: @icando And I know this question is old. I was just looking to do something similar (set the default for g++ to be c++11 if nothing else is defined) and found my way here via Google. Once I figured out a solution to my problem, I figured I would put it here for the benefit of anyone else looking for something similar in the future.

Comment: thanks for sharing your answer.  I think it may work for -std=c++11 flag, but you can see from my question, -march=i386 will be passed in if no -march is specified in the command line.  So your stuff won't match anything thus takes no effect.